# Multiple baseUrl in RequireJS config

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I have two locations for my JavaScript files, is it possible to set two baseUrls so that I can move them later without having to update loads of paths?

e.g.:

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: 'bower_components',
    paths: {
        backbone: 'backbone/backbone',
        underscore: 'underscore/underscore'
    }
});

requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: 'js',
    paths: {
        main: 'main'
    }
});
```

This format overwrites the baseUrl on the second call.  I could just declare two variables to hold this, but there a more elegant, RequireJS-ish way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe it is possible. Require's not going to try loading from one base-url and fall back to retry others upon failure. If you don't want paths in your scripts' `require` calls you can consider specifying `bundles`. See the [configuration docs](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config). I would personally just set a path config for `app` to be `js/main`.

Comment: `bundles` don't address this problem, a bundle is just a source file with multiple defines inside, `bundles` config option maps from bundle module id to included module ids (not to paths).